# Does this "anyone" mean "no one"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I'm guessing the following sentence means *"**no one** has respects for my perspective/opinion/insight/sentiments/humor"*.

> Suffice it to say, it's been a steady decline towards hopelessness
> that anyone in my circles (social and professional) has any genuine
> respect for my perspective/opinion/insight/sentiments/humor.

https://www.quora.com/If-you-re-autistic-do-you-isolate-yourself-to-accept-many-people-s-choices-not-to-hear-about-any-topics-and-or-listen-talk-to-you/answer/Neda-Sterling?ch=10&oid=1477743740093004&share=ab26b3d6&srid=56dna&target_type=answer

Is it right?
If so, how can I tell the "anyone" represents "no one"?

Comment: Yes, the writer has lost hope of finding even one person who shows respect. No one is showing respect. It's the word *hopelessness* that tells us that so far, zero 'friends' show respect. Not 1,000%, but close to 0 for all preactical purposes.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, Thank you. It seems plausible for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone here does not mean no one.
The author is hopeless that anyone has respect for them.
Or in other words hoping that more than no one has respect for the author

Comment: So, does the author feel uncomfortable when someone has respect for the author? @Bram

Comment: No, the author is losing hope (steady decline towards hopelessness) that someone still has respect for them.

Comment: To paraphrase, "I am losing hope that even one person in my circle respects my work." So while the _sentiment_ is that he thinks that nobody respects his work, "no one" cannot be substituted here. He is losing hope. What kind of hope? The hope that anyone respects his contributions.

Comment: I think I understood. There is no chance (= hopelessness) that anyone has respect for my perspective/opinion/insight/sentiments/humor.

Comment: @K.N. Yes, exactly. "[...] a steady decline towards hopelessness" = I had hope but have lost most or all of it.